# React Native Elements Handle ListItem click

Tags: react-native

I use `React Native Elements` library to create list items inside of a `Flat List`. I show a list of users and i need to handle style after a click.

My code is :

```
<View style={{flex: 1}}>
  <FlatList
    data={this.state.data}
    renderItem={({item}) => (
      <ListItem
        leftAvatar={{source: {uri: item.avatar}}}
        title={`${item.firstName} ${item.lastName}`}
        // subtitle={item.email}
        chevron
        onPress={this.onItemClickHandler}
      />
    )}
    keyExtractor={item => item.email}
    ItemSeparatorComponent={this.renderSeparator}
    ListHeaderComponent={this.renderHeader}
  />
  <Button
    title='Suivant'
    onPress={() => navigation.navigate('LastStepToShare')}
    containerStyle={{marginBottom: 15}}
  />
</View>
```

How can i edit the background of a clicked `ListItem` item ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
<FlatList
  data={this.state.data}
  renderItem={({item, index}) => {
    const {selectedIndex} = this.state;
    const itemStyle = selectedIndex === index ? styles.selected : styles.notSelected;
    return (
      <ListItem
        leftAvatar={{source: {uri: item.avatar}}}
        title={`${item.firstName} ${item.lastName}`}
        style={itemStyle}
        // subtitle={item.email}
        chevron
        onPress={() => this.onItemClickHandler(index)}
      />
    )
  }}
  keyExtractor={item => item.email}
  ItemSeparatorComponent={this.renderSeparator}
  ListHeaderComponent={this.renderHeader}
/>
```

and in your `onItemClickHandler` function, set the `selectedIndex` value in the state using `this.setState`.

Basically, get the selected index thanks to the `onPress` event and compare it to the current index from the `renderItem` function. Based on that, you can set a style variable.

Comment: i tried your solution but the onPress event does not work, i get all the items with the notSelected style and i can't edit the current selected item . i tried to bind onItemClickHandler in the constructor and  also it doesn't work

Comment: can you see this ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58837849/react-native-elements-handle-selected-listitem-style

Answer (score 0):

You can easily store the state of active Item, and set state on `onItemClickHandler` function, now you can change style according to state of item  (is it active or not)

```
<View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
<FlatList
  data={this.state.data}
  renderItem={({ item }) => (
    <ListItem
      style={this.state.active === item.id ? styles.active : null} //***
      leftAvatar={{ source: { uri: item.avatar } }}
      title={`${item.firstName} ${item.lastName}`}
      // subtitle={item.email}
      chevron
      onPress={() => this.onItemClickHandler(item.id)}
    />
  )}
  keyExtractor={item => item.email}
  ItemSeparatorComponent={this.renderSeparator}
  ListHeaderComponent={this.renderHeader}
/>

<Button
  title='Suivant'
  onPress={() => navigation.navigate('LastStepToShare')}
  containerStyle={{ marginBottom: 15 }}
/>
</View>
```

and

```
this.onItemClickHandler(id) => {
  this.setState({
    active: id
  })
}
```

Comment: hello, why you use prevState ?

Comment: Hi, I use to write prevState, it's not require in this case

Comment: I received a warning :  Cannot update during an existing state transition ...

Comment: can you see this ? :

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58837849/react-native-elements-handle-selected-listitem-style

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample code snippet, this might help you :

```
<FlatList
    data={this.getAllTask()}
    renderItem={({ item, index }) =>
    <TouchableHighlight
        onPress={() => {this.props.navigation.navigate('OtherPage', {text: item.task_name, index: index})}}>
            <View style={styles.customRowContainer}>
                <View style={styles.listContainer}>
                    <Image source={require('../Img/ic_task_icon.png')} style={styles.photo} />
                    <View style={styles.container_text}>
                        <Text style={styles.title}>
                            {item.task_name}
                        </Text>
                        <Text style={styles.description}>
                            ETA : {item.task_eta}
                        </Text>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </View>
        </TouchableHighlight>}
    keyExtractor={item => item.id}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to change the background color *only while the item is pressed* (ie. change back when the finger is up), you can customise `underlayColor` and `activeOpacity` of the underlying `TouchableHighlight` to achieve what you need:

```
<ListItem underlayColor="#ff0000" activeOpacity={1} title="Title" onPress={yourClickHandler} />
```