# React Native Elements Handle selected ListItem style

Tags: react-native

I post again my question with some code modifications.
I need to set a specific style for the selected item in my List of items.
My code is :

```
 constructor (props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      selectedIndex: null
    }
  }

<FlatList
                data={this.state.data}
                renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
                  <ListItem
                    leftAvatar={{ source: { uri: item.avatar } }}
                    title={`${item.firstName} ${item.lastName}`}
                    // subtitle={item.email}
                    chevron
                    onPress={() => {
                      this.setState({
                        selectedIndex: index
                      })
                      console.log('####################')
                      console.log(this.state.selectedIndex)
                      console.log(index)
                      console.log('####################')
                    }}
                    containerStyle={
                      this.state.selectedIndex === index
                        ? styles.active
                        : styles.inactive
                    }
                  />
                )}
                keyExtractor={item => item.email}
                ItemSeparatorComponent={this.renderSeparator}
                ListHeaderComponent={this.renderHeader}
              />
```

When i tested in the console i got those values :

```
####################
####################
2
3
####################
####################
3
0
####################
####################
0
1
####################
####################
1
2
####################
####################
2
3
####################
####################
3
4
####################
####################
4
5
####################
####################
5
6
####################
####################
6
3
####################
####################
3
3
####################
####################
3
3
####################
####################
3
3
####################
####################
3
2
####################
####################
2
2
####################
```

The selectedIndex state got the index value when press an item but i can't edit the style cause the component is not re-rendering.

My style is :

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  active: {
    backgroundColor: 'green'
  },
  inactive: {
    backgroundColor: 'grey'
  }
})
```

I need to apply the active class when selectedIndex is equal to index but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the `this.state.selectedIndex` to the `extraData` of the `FlatList` for the component to be rerendered.

```
<FlatList
    data={this.state.data}
    renderItem={({ item, index }) => (...)}
    extraData={this.state.selectedIndex}
/>
```

See the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html#extradata) for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried extracting the setState from the flatlist into its own function. I'd never call setState inside a onPress (spoiler: it's an asynchronous function).

A call to setState isn't synchronous. It creates a "pending state transition.". You should explicitly pass the new input value as part of the event being raised.

I'd make a new function called setIndex and put the logic in there.

```
setIndex = async (index) => {
  await this.setState({
    selectedIndex: index
})
```

and just use that in the onPress:

```
onPress={() => setIndex(index)}
```